# Deferred conditional assignment in makefiles

Tags: makefile

I understand deferred assignment (assigning things with `=` as opposed to `:=`), and I understand how to use `#ifneq` and similar commands for conditional assignment.  How do I make a deferred conditional assignment?

Here is a psuedo-code example:

```
FOO = defined
BAR = $(defined(FOO) ? one : two)

test_1: $(BAR) #depends on one

FOO =

test_2: $(BAR) #depends on two
```

The main purpose of this is to configure my linker flags on the fly for static and dynamic builds.  Building statically is more annoying that building dynamically because of circular dependencies (in addition to `-fPIC` removal and such).  In this way, a couple variables change based on the definedness of `STATIC` (i.e. `make STATIC=y`).  I could just define `VAR` and `VAR_STATIC` for each varable that needs variants, but I'd like to keep it has one global switch.

The kicker is that some submakes define rules that *must* be compiled dynamically in addition to rules that don't.  Therefore, only a select few rules need to ignore the flag.  This is why I would like to be able to toggle it on and off within the same Makefile.

Alternatively again, I could just reinclude the global Makefile when I need to toggle a flag, but that would not be preferred.

EDIT: From Come Raczy's solution, this is the specific syntax for my particular problem:

```
#Makefile
all: test_1 test_2

CFLAGS = -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -O3
CFLAGS += $(if $(DSYM),-g,)
test_1: DSYM:=y
test_2: DSYM:=

test_%: test.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm -f test test_sym test_back
```

Comment: The [How make Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) section of the GNU make Manual explains what parts are immediate and what are deferred. In case that's of use.

Comment: Is the "must be dynamic" need per-target or per-submake? Would un-exporting/unsetting `STATIC` before the appropriate sub-make calls work?

Comment: I would like it to be per-target if I understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it is a combination of a conditional, deferred and per-target. Something like this:

```
BAR = $(if $(FOO), one, two)
all: test_1 test_2
FOO = defined
test_1: local_BAR:=$(BAR) #depends on one
FOO =
test_2: local_BAR:=$(BAR) #depends on two
test_%:
        echo $*: $(local_BAR)
```

Comment: @Aggieboy when the  number of possible configurations increases, the '$(or ...)' function can also be handy

Comment: Looks like I need to go back and read *all* of the Makefile functions available.  Thank you sir!